# How to get input field values based on classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a form where i am showing input fields using loop. all fields have classes.
Basically there are 3 fields.
1 - quantity
2 - price
3 - total

as the input fields are in loop. so here is the problem that i want to show total from the quantity*price == total
but i want to calculate total on click.

please help

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Presumably you would read the values from your inputs and perform arithmetic on those values.  Have you tried?  What didn't work?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank You for your comment. if i use only 1 input for quantity, 1 input for price and 1 input for result... then i can get values through ID but here i am using loop to display the inputs.... so here are multiple inputs and we can't use ID... then how can we access it with classes?

Answer (score 1):

What you would need to do is extract the values with JavaSript then apply The calculation and update your total

```js
//get the HTML elements

var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
var price = document.getElementById('price');
var total = document.getElementById('total');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

function calc(){

var calc= quantity.value * price.value;
result.innerHTML = calc;

}
```

```html
<form >
quantity:<br>
<input type='text' name='quantity' id='quantity'><br>

price :<br>
 <input type='text' name='price' id='price'><br>


<input type="button" value="Calculate " onclick="calc()" ><br>
</form ><br>
total = <div id = 'result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this only works for 1 inputs.... what if i use this inputs using loop???

Comment: <form > foreach($products as $product)  
quantity:<br>
<input type='text' name='quantity' id='quantity'><br>

price :<br>
 <input type='text' name='price' id='price'><br>


<input type="button" value="Calculate " onclick="calc()" ><br>
</form ><br>
total = <div id = 'result'></div> endforeach

Comment: You see a form is usually used for user input . If you creating multiple records in table would be better  . If you running it on a list of products it would be wiser to calculate  it on a table ... Where is your data comming from ? PHP

Comment: i will be using 1 form, but the input fields will be maximum then 1. like if i have 10 products in database.... then there will be 30 inputs. for product 1: 1 for quantity, 1 for price and 1 for total..... and same for the rest...

Comment: admin is saving the product info (name, image, price) in the database... then on 1 page retrieving all the products with their info in a form and with 3 inputs (quantity, price, total)...... as the fields are dynamic...and i want to calculate the total from quantity*price.......

Comment: Post some your code and lets see if we can help you with it . Specifically the foreach statement

Comment: @foreach($Coffees as $Coffee)
            <?php
            if (isset($Coffee->image)) {
                $File = Storage::url('Products/'.$Coffee->image);
            }
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="stats-widget stats-widget">
                    <div class="widget-header">
                        <h3>{{$Coffee->product_name}}</h3>
                        <p>Retail Price: {{$Coffee->retail_price}}</p>
                        <p>{{$Coffee->description}}</p>
                    </div>

Comment: <div class="col-md-12 unit">
                       <img src="{{ $File }}">
                    </div> 
                    <div class="widget-stats-list">
                        <ul>
                            <li>

Comment: <label class="label">Quantity</label>
                                <div class="input quantity-events">
                                    <input class="form-control first_field_quantity" type="text" id="" name="first_field_quantity">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>

Comment: <label class="label">Customer Pays</label>
                                <div class="input">
                                    <input class="form-control first_field_price" type="text"  value="{{$Coffee->customer_pays}}" name="first_field_price">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><label class="label">Total</label>
                                <div class="input">

Comment: <input class="form-control first_field_total" type="text"  name="first_field_total">
                                </div> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach

Comment: above is the code.. but sorry for not proper design of the code.. because their is no space...

Comment: The best approach you have with that code is to do the calculation in PHP and map it to the form elements . To do it in JS means that you would have to map each value to a unique ID and calculate each one separately .. That the long way of doing things .... THe other suggestion I would make is to convert the php to a JSON object then run the calculations and map it to html elements with JS

Comment: Give me about an 40 mins I work on something for you 

I noticed that quantity was not included from PHP so what you possibly trying to do is get the image and Price list from foreach in PHP and get the quantity from a user input

Comment: @AleemZada updated my answer with your code, for jQuery solution. I also agree that you should do calculations server-side if possible. Malicious users will be able to *trick* the browser and could manipulate the form before submitting it.

Comment: I posted a new answer to reflect how I'm working with PHP in your scenario . Use that as the boilerplate and you can get your working through that

Comment: Also just retype you question with a little more description  and these other guys wont down vote you so much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent form as reference to specific items. This is helpful if you have multiple forms. Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  function calcTotal(p, q) {
    var t = parseFloat(p) * parseInt(q);
    t = t.toFixed(2);
    return t;
  }

  $(".first_field_quantity").change(function(e) {
    var l = $(this).closest("ul");
    var pr = $(".first_field_price", l).val();
    if (pr.slice(0, 1) == "$") {
      pr = pr.slice(1);
    }
    $(".first_field_total", l).val("$" + calcTotal(pr, $(this).val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
  <div class="stats-widget stats-widget">
    <div class="widget-header">
      <h3>Coffee Product</h3>
      <p>Retail Price: 12.00</p>
      <p>Description 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 unit">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PGPviCM.jpg" width="240px">
    </div>
    <div class="widget-stats-list">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="label">Quantity</label>
          <div class="input quantity-events">
            <input class="form-control first_field_quantity" type="text" name="first_field_quantity" value="1">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="label">Customer Pays</label>
          <div class="input">
            <input class="form-control first_field_price" type="text" value="$12.00" name="first_field_price" readonly>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="label">Total</label>
          <div class="input">
            <input class="form-control first_field_total" type="text" name="first_field_total" value="$12.00" readonly>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are quite a few Changes I made to your script by using echo instead of pure hTML tags so I could use just the dot notation

- The script updates on when the user updates a quantity filed it calculates it automatically
- The script uses an enumerater $i which iterates with your list and allows Javascript to calculate the things base on that iterator for item keys
- Then the image was a straight string fetch bases on it being in the folder
- PHP values I call by $Coffee['retail_price'] and not with arrow syntax by $Coffee->'retail_price'

  ```
      <?


  $Coffees = array(
      "item1" => array(
          "retail_price" => "31",
          "image" => "img.jpg",
          "product_name" => "Machanto",
          "description" => "Machanto Creamy ",
      ),
         "item2" => array(
          "retail_price" => "22",
          "image" => "img.jpg",
          "product_name" => "Espresso",
          "description" => "Machanto Strong ",
      ),
         "item3" => array(
          "retail_price" => "12",
          "image" => "img.jpg",
          "product_name" => "Chochlate",
          "description" => "Machanto sweet ",
      )
  );

  // Printing all the keys and values one by one
  //$keys = array_keys($Coffees);
  //for($i = 0; $i < count($Coffees); $i++) {
  //    echo $keys[$i] . "{<br>";
  //   foreach($Coffees[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
  //       echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
  //    }
  //    echo "}<br>";
  //}



  //set an iteration Value
  $i = 0;
  $File = '';
  foreach($Coffees as $Coffee) {

  if (isset($Coffee['image'])) {
      //$File = Storage::url('Products/'.$Coffee['image']); 
      $File = 'Products/'.$Coffee['image']; 
      echo $File;
  }

  //print_r($Coffee);

      echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"> <div class="stats-widget stats-widget">';
      echo '<div class="widget-header"> <h3>'. $Coffee['product_name'] .'</h3> ';

  echo '<p>Retail Price: '.$Coffee['retail_price'].'</p> <p>'.$Coffee['description'].'</p> </div>';

  echo '<div class="col-md-12 unit">';
  echo ' <img src="'. $File .'"> </div> ';
  echo ' <div class="widget-stats-list"> <table> ';
  echo ' <td> ';

   // Quantity (between 1 and 5): <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">

  echo '  <label class="label">Quantity</label> <div class="input quantity-events">';
  echo '  <input class="form-control first_field_quantity" type="number" id="quantity'.$i.'" name="first_field_quantity" min="1" max="5" onChange="calc('.$i.')"> </div> </td> ';
  echo ' <td> ';

  echo '  <label class="label">Customer Pays</label> <div class="input"> ';
  echo '      <input class="form-control first_field_price" type="text" id="price'.$i.'" value="'.$Coffee['retail_price'].'" name="first_field_price" readonly> </div> </td> ';

  echo '      <td>';
  echo '      <label class="label" >Total</label> <div class="input"> ';

  echo '<input class="form-control first_field_total" id="total'.$i.'" type="text" name="first_field_total"> </div> </td> ';
  echo '</table> ';
  echo '</div> ';
  echo '</div> ';
  echo '</div>';


      $i++;
  } ?>

  <script>
  function calc(i)
  {
  //alert(i);

  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity'+i);
  var price = document.getElementById('price'+i);
  var total = document.getElementById('total'+i);




  var cal= quantity.value * price.value;
  total.value = cal;



  }
  </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using jquery plugin. https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Do-Calculations-Form-Fields-AutoCalc.html

Thank You all for your valuable time.